# rails 3.0: ActionController::Base render()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone explain where render() comes from in
ActionController::Base?

I managed to trace it down only that far:

ActionController::Base includes ActionController::Rendering module where
render() method is defined. This definition however calls to render() of
the superclass. Superclass is ActionController::Metal. Which in its
turn inherits from AbstractController::Base. None of those have render
() either defined or included.

Now, presumably it comes from AbstractController::Rendering, but I'm
really missing how it gets included.

Comment: @artemave, you've asked 18 questions and have only accepted answers for four of them. If an answer has helped you then please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `render` method you call in your action is defined in `ActionController::Base`.

```
def render(action = nil, options = {}, &blk)
  options = _normalize_options(action, options, &blk)
  super(options)
end
```

This method passes the call to `super` which calls the `render` method defined in `ActionController::Rendering`.

```
def render(options)
  super
  self.content_type ||= options[:_template].mime_type.to_s
  response_body
end
```

`ActionController::Rendering` is effectively a Module, mixed into the ActionController::Base class at the beginning of the `base.rb` file.

```
include ActionController::Redirecting
include ActionController::Rendering # <--
include ActionController::Renderers::All
```

In turns, `ActionController::Rendering` includes `AbstractController::Rendering` as you can see in the `ActionController::Rendering` module definition.

```
module ActionController
  module Rendering
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      include AbstractController::Rendering
      include AbstractController::LocalizedCache
    end
```

`AbstractController::Rendering` provides a `render` method which is the final method invoked  in the render chain.

```
# Mostly abstracts the fact that calling render twice is a DoubleRenderError.
# Delegates render_to_body and sticks the result in self.response_body.
def render(*args)
  if response_body
    raise AbstractController::DoubleRenderError, "Can only render or redirect once per action"
  end

  self.response_body = render_to_body(*args)
end
```

The full chain is

```
AbstractController::Base#render 
--> super() 
--> ActionController::Rendering#render
--> super()
--> AbstractController::Rendering#render
--> render_to_body
```

Comment: "super invokes a method with the same name as the current one, in the superclass of the current class"

ActionController::Rendering is NOT A PARENT CLASS for ActionController::Base. It is INCLUDED MODULE. So how come super can work the way you described?

Comment: When the class A includes the module B, B becomes an ancestor of A. See `Object#ancestors`. When you call `super` in A, it searches for a method with the same name in all ancestors of class A, including B. In Ruby you can extend a Class by Inheritance and/or using Mixins.

Comment: This is certainly a gotcha of the day.

Comment: So if a class includes two modules with method a() defined, only one (from last included module) gets imported. Or, better, first module you include defines a() which you rely on and the second module includes some other module which includes some other module which includes some other module with method a(). One tough debugging session guarantied. This smells so bad. Probably deserves its own question - it is interesting how people get around this.

Comment: If both module `A` and `B` defines `foo()` and you include `B` and `A` into `C` which defines its on `foo()`, there's probably something wrong at architectural level in your code. Ruby silently allows you to do so but it doesn't mean you should. ;)

Comment: No no no, David Blaine! You include some library module with only foo() defined. This module includes other module which has got bar() defined. You don't know about it. And now, all of a sudden, super inside bar() defined in your class goes mental.

Answer (score 0):

`render` is defined in [`AbstractController::Rendering`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb). It calls `render_to_body`, which in turn dispatches to other methods. It's a bit of a rabbit hole, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the original question.